# How does function decorated with `route()` from flask receives arguments?

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, routes, decorator

I am plotting a Matplotlib figure with flask:

```
@app.route('/plot.png')
def plot_png():
    x = range(100)
    y = np.random.randint(0,100,100)
    fig = create_figure(x,y)
    output = io.BytesIO()
    FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(output)
    return flask.Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')
```

**works**,
but I need to feed the arguments to plot_png:

```
@app.route('/plot.png/<y>/')
def plot_png(y):
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    fig = create_figure(x,y)
    output = io.BytesIO()
    FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(output)
    return flask.Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')
```

**doesn't work.**

How do I make to feed the arguments to plot_png?
Thank you!

Comment: Try dropping the trailing `/` from the URL. The syntax is otherwise correct.

Comment: @chepner I got `ValueError: urls must start with a leading slash`

Comment: Trailing, not leading: `'/plot.png/<y>'`

Comment: @chepner sorry for that. Not working with `'/plot.png/<ys>'`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error, or is `plot_png` simply not being called at all?

Comment: @chepner I get `"GET /plot.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -` and I don't see the plot. Sorry for my inaccuracy

Comment: You appear to have stopped defining `/plot.png` at all, and you aren't trying to fetch `/plot.png/6` (for example).

Comment: @chepner  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j-vuizsfJnPYRVpLZlfTOMbNGBVta7y_AXx5apetLNo/edit?usp=sharing is. the script.

Answer (score 1):

As written, `y` will be a string.

```
@app.route('/plot.png/<int:y>')
```

will fix that. Add a trailing slash if you need one.

Comment: I still get `"GET /plot.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: That's  because you don't have an `@app.route()` that matches it. There's an example in https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/ (in Rendering Templates) that might help.

Comment: Thank you. `@app.route()` that doesn't match what?

Comment: If you defined `plot_png` twice, the second overwrites the first one. Some languages would treat `plot_png()` and `plot_png(y)` as separate functions/methods. Python doesn't.